# How to reference output rows with window functions?

Tags: postgresql

Suppose I have a table with `quantity` column.

```
CREATE TABLE transfers (
  user_id integer,
  quantity integer,
  created timestamp default now()
);
```

I'd like to iteratively go thru a partition using window functions, but access the output rows, not the input table rows.

To access the input table rows I could do something like this:

```
SELECT LAG(quantity, 1, 0)
  OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY created)
FROM transfers;
```

I need to access the previous output row to calculate the next output row. How can i access the lag row in the output? Something like:

```
CREATE VIEW balance AS
SELECT LAG(balance.total, 1, 0) + quantity AS total
  OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY created)
FROM transfers;
```

**Edit**

This is a minimal example to support the question of how to access the previous output row within a window partition. I don't actually want a sum.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you attempt to calculate a `running sum`. Luckily that's just what `Sum()` window function does:

```
WITH transfers AS(
    SELECT i, random()-0.3 AS quantity  FROM generate_series(1,100) as i
)
SELECT i, quantity, sum(quantity) OVER (ORDER BY i) from transfers;
```

Comment: It's just an example, i want to use previous output row in case statements and calculations.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, looking at the question, that the only you need is to calculate a cumulative sum.
To calculate a cumulative summ use this query:

```
SELECT *,
      SUM( CASE WHEN quantity IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE quantity END) 
      OVER ( PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY created
             ROWS BETWEEN unbounded preceding AND current row
              ) As cumulative_sum
FROM transfers
ORDER BY user_id, created
;
```

But if you want more complex calculations, especially containing some conditions (decisions) that depend on a result from prevoius row, then you need a recursive approach.

Comment: Yeah, it's just an example, i need to do fancy stuff.